# Visual Studio Code: Open current HTML file in browser (launch.json)

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code and would like to debug the currently open HTML file in a web browser, Microsoft Edge in this case. My project folder is the webroot of a locally installed web server (http://localhost).
I have installed the VS Code extension "Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code" and created a launch.json configuration with the following content:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge and open the Edge DevTools",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "vscode-edge-devtools.debug",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "url": "http://localhost/${relativeFile}"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when i launch this debugger, Microsoft Edge opens with the URL `http://localhost/$%7BrelativeFile%7D`, so it seems that the variable ${relativeFile} is not resolved.

How can I fix this and achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

The relativeFile will refer to the current opened file relative to workspaceFolder. You need to specify the path of the folder opened in VS Code, the webroot

```
{

"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge and open the Edge DevTools",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "vscode-edge-devtools.debug",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"      // "${workspaceFolder}/src"
        "url": "http://localhost/${relativeFile}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ref:- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Update per comments:-

%7B and %7D are ASCII codes for `{` and `}`. While you're in launch.json, check the bottom right of VScode and see what the encoding is? It should be UTF-8

Comment: I added the line `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",` as suggested, however the URL is still `http://localhost/$%7BrelativeFile%7D` in Edge.

Comment: I have also tried other variables for the "url" property, such as ${file} and ${fileBasename}, they don't resolve either.

Comment: Updated the answer. can you try that.

Comment: json does not work with back ticks

Comment: oops, sorry didn't realise that. can you check in VScode settings what the encoding is set to?

Comment: It's already set to UTF-8. And as @rioV8 noted, back ticks or single quotes don't work in json.